# Configuration Options while `apt-get install`ing

Tags: 13.04, apt

Is there a way to set configuration options for packages or Makefiles being run while `apt-get` is installing software?

I'm currently installing `freetds-dev` by running `apt-get install freetds-dev tdsodbc`

For the `freetds-dev` package I'd like to set the `--with-open-ssl=OPEN_SSL_DIR` option during the configuration step.  It seems like common enough of a need that the standard install tools would provide hooks for it...but it doesn't look like it from the man pages and google.

Am I stuck writing the full install/uninstall script manually rather than just `sudo apt-get`?  Or is there a way around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, this is not possible. Developers use different tools, languages, installation scripts. Some packages use autoconf, some don't. Some take options, some need a modification of a Makefile or of a shell or perl script.

You can download the source package (`apt-get source package`), modify it, compile and install the modified version. It is quite simple. Say, package name is `freetds`.

1. Get the stuff necessary to build the package.

   ```
   apt-get build-dep freetds
   ```
2. Get the package source

   ```
   apt-get source freetds
   ```
3. Now a directory called `freetds-0.91` has been created. Enter the directory and do necessary modifications.
4. Recompile the package.

   ```
   cd freetds-0.91
   dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b
   ```
5. Install the new package using dpkg. The new package name will be something like `freetds-dev_0.91-3_[architecture].deb`, for example `freetds-dev_0.91-3_amd64.deb`.

   ```
   cd ..
   sudo dpkg -i freetds-0.91-3_amd64.deb
   ```